# Django DEBUG mode to only apply for a set of whitelisted IPs

Tags: django, debugging, production-environment

I have some strange bug that seems to only occur on my production environment, not even on staging.

The limited trace that django emails is insufficient for effectively debugging (no local vars etc) but I can't set the entire production server to DEBUG=True since any accidental arrival by a visitor to an error page would expose much sensitive data.

Is there any elegant way in which I could whitelist a few IPs of my team and only for requests arriving from these IPs django will behave as if DEBUG is True?

Comment: Use Sentry (http://getsentry.com). They have a hosted solution, now, if you just don't want to take the time to set it up yourself, but it's still available as open source on github.

Answer (score 0):

The one option is to "runserver" at the same environment your production works
The other option is to use [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry) which besides a lot of cool stuff provides local vars for exceptions